# Failling to ssh into Raspberry pi PuTTy showing "unable to open connection to raspberrypi.local Host does not exist!" error

Tags: raspberry-pi2

I have been using my Rpi for some time now using ssh with no problems until recently when i tried to login using the default password and it refused. After several attempts i packed it away, so it happens that i wanted to use it again earlier on today and when i tried accessing it using PuTTy it gave me a "unable to open connection to raspberrypi.local Host does not exist!" error. so i got a new memory card with Noobs on it reinstalled the OS only to get the same error, "unable to open connection to raspberrypi.local Host does not exist!". i have tried all i can i need help..

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem (connecting from a Windows 10 PC to a Pi Zero over USB using PuTTY), and I solved it by following this guide and by using a non-OTG USB cable/adapter: http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/. My issue seemed to be that the Pi was getting locked into a host-state while using the OTG micro-USB to USB adapter and thus couldn't receive any commands over the "ethernet" USB connection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your devices in your network? And did you try it with "raspberrypi" instead of `raspberrypi.local`?

Good luck!